# Initialize a struct that contains pointer to a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to initialize a struct that contains different types of variables. For example, suppose I have

```
struct population {
    int *ids;
    double *incomes;
    struct good **goodsdistn; // This is the one I am having trouble with.
};

struct population popn;
```

I want to initialize `popn` using the parameters that are defined in another struct, say

```
struct params {
    int numpeople;
    // there are other parameters here, not relevant for the question.
};

struct params parameters = {.numpeople = 50};
```

To initialize `popn` I am thinking of doing the following:

(1) Define the following function outside  `main()`

```
void create_population(struct population *popn, struct params *parameters)
{
    popn -> ids = malloc(sizeof(int) * parameters -> numpeople); //This works
    popn -> incomes = malloc(sizeof(double) * parameters -> numpeople); //This works
    popn -> goodsdistn = malloc(sizeof(???) * parameters -> numpeople);
    // What do I put in place of ??? when I have a pointer to a pointer to struct good.

}
```

(2) Within `main()` call this function to initialize popn (later I can then fill the struct members):

```
create_population(&popn, &parameters);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why `struct good **goodsdistn` and not `struct good *goodsdistn`?

Comment: @trojanfoe `goodsdistn` will be array of `struct good pointers`. But I will think further about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment I also believe that a `struct good **` is overkill, but did you know you can use `sizeof` on variables?

```
void create_population(struct population *popn, struct params *parameters)
{
    popn -> ids = malloc(sizeof(popn->ids[0]) * parameters -> numpeople);
    popn -> incomes = malloc(sizeof(popn->incomes[0]) * parameters -> numpeople);
    popn -> goodsdistn = malloc(sizeof(popn->goodsdistn[0]) * parameters -> numpeople);

}
```

If you did want to use the type identifier then you could use `sizeof(struct good *)` or the generic `sizeof(void *)`. All data pointers have the same size in C.

Comment: Thanks. But will this work when there is nothing in `ids`, `incomes` etc. arrays when `popn` is initialized. That is, does ids[0] make sense. I will look into the need for struct good **.

Comment: @Curious2learn Yes, it will work. You are not actually dereferencing the pointers, but just querying how big the dereferenced type would be. `sizeof` is a compiler operator, not a runtime function.

Comment: Thank you. This is great. I will try this out and accept the answer after that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You want the following in place of `???`:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct good *))
```